# ATP Synthase EC number

Tags: enzymes

Why ATP synthase EC number is 7(Translocase)?

My textbook says it's a hydrolase but when i checked its EC number it was changed to 7.

And also ATPase(adensointriphosphatase) page that was previously classified as hydrolase is deleted in qmul.ac.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What textbook is this? An ATP synthase is not a hydrolase, since it does [not use water to break a chemical bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolase) (at least not in its primary function). However, it [couples proton translocation with ATP synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_synthase). Therefore it is a translocase.

See the following passage from [qmul.ac.uk](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iubmb/newsletter/2018.html) what category 7 is and why e.g. ATPase is classified as translocase rather than as hydrolase. (It is a hydrolase as well, but it's not its primary function.)

> **Translocases (EC 7): A new EC Class**
>
> Six enzyme classes have been recognized since the first Enzyme
> classification and nomenclature list was first approved by the
> International Union of Biochemistry in 1961. These were based on the
> type of reaction catalysed: Oxidoreductases (EC 1), Transferases (EC
> 2), Hydrolases (EC 3), Lyases (EC 4), Isomerases (EC 5) and Ligases
> (EC 6). However, it has become apparent that none of these could
> describe the important group of enzymes that catalyse the movement of
> ions or molecules across membranes or their separation within
> membranes. Several of these involve the hydrolysis of ATP and had been
> previously classified as ATPases (EC 3.6.3.-), although the hydrolytic
> reaction is not their primary function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't think it's a surprise that some "old" sources use this classification because as mentioned in qmul,ATP synthase was classified as 3.6.3 from 2000-2018.And if you don't mind i have another question:Do all enzymes that seem to belong in two classes regrading the direction that we are looking at,are classified regarding the "primary direction" that enzyme usually catalyzes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy. There is a whole catalogue of rules for the naming and classifications of enzymes: https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iubmb/enzyme/rules.html.